# Why the line is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, path, geometry

**Update:**

**Reason:**

*strokeCollection* is the data i got from somewhere.
then i change it to *Path.Data* like this:

```
foreach (var stroke in strokeCollection)
{
    pathGeometry.AddGeometry(stroke.GetGeometry());
}
```

Unfortunately, the *GetGeometry* method will give me a path like ***1***.it is empty.
In order to ensure stroke have all been included into the path, *GetGeometry* method is the stroke's border.

**Question:**

When I set my strokethickness to 1px, the line is empty. like *1*.

```
 <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Data="{Binding PathData}" />
```

and then I binding the line's fill to the stroke. it changed to *2*.

```
 <Path Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" Fill="{Binding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="1" Data="{Binding PathData}" />
```

and I think it thickness is 2px.

I change the line thickness to 10px, and stroke to `#1AFF0000`, it changed to *4*.

**behidecode.cs:**

```
Stroke = new SolidColorBrush("#1AFF0000");
```

**xaml:**

```
<Path Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" Fill="{Binding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="10" Data="{Binding PathData}" />
```

[image]

### Questions

1. How to draw a solid line, the width is 1px?
2. How to clear the darkred in the *4*?

Comment: What is _3_? What are your data?

Comment: if you want to draw line then you can do it directly using line object..why are using path ?

Comment: 3 is two intersecting lines . Their intersection is white. I do not want it to appear .

Comment: @tanuj_loop oh, my fault , is path, not a line.

Comment: @CédricBignon data is convert from Stroke.i use Stroke.GetGeometry().that is the reason ?

Comment: @GeminiYellow Probably!

Comment: @CédricBignon oh,yes, i have a StrokeCollection, and i convert it to PathGemetry, and binding my path's Data to the PathGemetry.

foreach (var stroke in strokeCollection)
{pathGeometry.AddGeometry(stroke.GetGeometry());}

Comment: @tanuj_loop ok,i known what is happend.i use Stroke.GetGeometry() method.the method use borders to create a geometry.

Comment: ok fine @GeminiYellow but  it is better if you post sufficient code related to  problem..

Answer (score 0):

look GemiiniYellow actually there problem with your data part i have checked the basic of how to draw path and find it working fine here is the code.

```
  <Path Stroke="DarkGoldenRod" StrokeThickness="2" 
Data="M 100,100 100,100 400,100 100,100" />
```

this is showing a perfect line ..